# Would you help me with tenses?

Tags: tense

She  to a movie tomorrow night.

Goes  is going

Would you tell me which one is correct and why?

And, could you tell me which one of the followings are more likely, stronger or sooner?

To be going to

Simple present

Simple future

Present progressive

Comment: Please don't use this forum as a homework solver. You have asked too many of such questions here, where it is not clear if you have actually put any efforts. It looks more like you just want someone to provide you the right answer.

Comment: Happy thank you so much for your replay. But, you should know the fact that I am a civil engineer in my country and I am a student who is studying linguistics too. Moreover, you must know that before I ask my question, I study them more than 10 times. I do not need your help if you do not want. thank you so much.

Comment: @Happy: I think your comment is unjustified. OP has clearly put some thought into this. Firstly, he has specifically identified three possible "verb tenses" that could all validly be used in the example. Secondly, he's identified three aspects of possible "difference" *(likely, stronger, sooner)*. That's more effort than many people put into their questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has often been pointed out on ELL, English only really has two "tenses" - present and "not present" (which usually equates to "past").

For *future* actions we often use "present progressive"...

> *"I can't go to the movie because **I'm washing** my hair tonight"*

We also use the "future progressive" (formed using the ["modal auxiliary"](http://www.wordpower.ws/grammar/gramch10.html) ***will***)

> *"But **you will be going** to the movie, so you can tell me tomorrow if it's any good or not"*

...and "simple future"...

> *"**John will go** to the movie with you, if you don't want to go alone"*

We sometimes use "simple present" for planned future activities...

> *"**I start** my new job tomorrow"*

...but in many contexts that usage is either dated, formal, or "literary".

---

The "most likely" verb form depends on the exact context (and to a considerable extend, the personal preferences of the speaker/writer), but probably for OP's example it would be *"She is going to a movie tomorrow night".*

I don't understand what "stronger" means in this context, so I can't say which form is "strongest".

If it's important to convey that something is going to happen "sooner", we might use something like...

> *"I don't have time to stay and chat because **I'm just about to go** to the movie"*

Comment: Well done. Thanks. But, would you order the tenses which you have provided in order of time?

Comment: I wonder which one is more likely, sooner,forthcoming, and on.

Comment: @nima: For most purposes it's meaningless to think of the different tenses in terms of distance into the future. Even *"The sun becomes a red giant in 7 billion years"* is credible, for example. It's the same for "likelihood" - if you want to indicate that something is only a *possibility*, not a certainty, you can say, for example, *"I **may** have an early night tonight instead of going to the movie"*.

Answer (score 1):

- she is going  to a movie tomorrow night, which is present progressive.

Simple rules which you can learn only by studying.